# BASH syntax to extract a parameter from a string

Tags: bash

I'm not a BASH and/or grep/AWK expert so hoping somebody can quickly help me with this simple query. Consider the following string:

> XenCenter.CustomFields.autostart: 120; last_shutdown_time:
>   20120418T11:24:32Z; last_shutdown_action: Destroy;
>   last_shutdown_initiator: external; last_shutdown_reason: halted;
>   import_task: OpaqueRef:1168d51a-e1ab-b02a-0db7-e6f9bd8fd269; mac_seed:
>   778079d8-5917-c5ce-4800-ee4321f3ed70

How do I extract the "120" bit above on the "autostart: 120" sub-string?

NOTE: the position and/or order of "XenCenter.CustomFields.autostart: 120" in the above string could and will change so can't rely upon it being the nth word

Answer (score 2):

AWK supports custom record and field seperators (default are newline and whitespace respectably).

When I look at your string it is a combination of variables separted by `;` and fields sperated by `:`

The following awk command sets these seperators (RS = record seperator, FS = field seperator) and checks if field 1 contains (the regex) "autostart" and prints the second field of the record:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=";" ; FS=": " } $1 ~ /autostart/ { print $2 }'
```

In a shell this produces:

```
$ echo $STRING | awk 'BEGIN { RS=";" ; FS=": " } $1 ~ /autostart/ { print $2 }'
120
```

Comment: This looks like the ticket - I knew AWK could be used for string parsing like this as I'd seen it in other scripts. Will try this later

Answer (score 0):

If you have this string stored in variable `x`, you can simply do this:

```
$ echo $x | awk {'print $2'}
120;
```

To eliminate the semicolon, you can use cut like:

```
$ echo $x | awk {'print $2'} | cut -f1 -d \;
120
```

This remains valid while you have the 120 separated by space from previous string and it is in the 2nd position (field).

Comment: I should have clarified that the position and/or order of items in the string can and will change

Answer (score 0):

assuming

```
var="XenCenter.CustomFields.autostart: 120; last_shutdown_time: 20120418T11:24:32Z; last_shutdown_action: Destroy; last_shutdown_initiator: external; last_shutdown_reason: halted; import_task: OpaqueRef:1168d51a-e1ab-b02a-0db7-e6f9bd8fd269; mac_seed: 778079d8-5917-c5ce-4800-ee4321f3ed70"
```

you can extract 120 by

```
echo $var | nawk -F"[:; ]" '{print $3}'
```

if you need to assign tat value to a var for further processing, just type this in your script

```
VALUE=$(echo $var | nawk -F"[:; ]" '{print $3}')
```

and 120 will be stored into $VALUE

Comment: nawk is by no means universal, and may be unwise to use unless it also fully implements POSIX awk.

Comment: agree, the command works with awk

Answer (score 0):

Or to do it in one step:

```
$ echo $x | awk -F'[ ;]' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I failed to add the caveat I've just added about order/position

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know for certain that the fields will always be in the order shown, something like this should work:

```
# assuming the line is stored in $x as others have done
echo $x | sed -e 's/; /\n/' | grep 'autostart:' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```